# Prove that $f=X^3-\sqrt{3}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I tried to prove it by following that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, we can't express it using a basis of  $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4})$. But I didn't get too far.

Comment: Try using the Eisenstein's criterion over $x^{6} - 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a root, meaning that $\alpha^6=3,$ so $\alpha$ is a root of $x^6-3$. Since the latter is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $\alpha$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, whereas the extension $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4})/\mathbb{Q}$ is of degree $4$, so $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4})$.

Comment: Because $4\nmid 6$.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin Because $6$ does not divide $4$ (I am not sure if you meant this or the other way around).

Comment: Well, we both need to be careful here. Why couldn't $\alpha$ be a root of an irrreducible quadratic, rather than linear?

Comment: The polynomial in question is of degree $3$, so it is reducible if and only if it has a root...